# How to pass mail attachment to POJO object with MULE ESB

Tags: java, attachment, mule

I'm trying to pass mail attachments from IMAP inbound endpoint to a JAVA component but it fails. The error message says "Message payload is of type: MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler".

The files in the attachments are Excel-files and I'm able to connect a Indound File endpoint but I want to use a IMAP endpoint instead.

How to get the message passed to the JAVA component of the typw FILE?

Here's my Mule config:

```
<flow name="imaptestflow" doc:name="imaptestflow">
    <imap:inbound-endpoint user="XXXXXXXX"
        password="XXXXX" host="XXXXXXX" port="143" doc:name="IMAP" disableTransportTransformer="true"/>
    <expression-transformer evaluator="attachments-list" expression="*.xls" doc:name="Expression"/>

    <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
    <all doc:name="All">
        <processor-chain>
            <component class="xlsFileRead" doc:name="Java"/>
        </processor-chain>
        <processor-chain>
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="c:\out" outputPattern="#[groovy:payload.getName()]" doc:name="File"/>
        </processor-chain>
    </all>
</flow>
```

The Java-Class is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.CellType;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
public class xlsFileRead {
public void readFromFile(Object input)throws IOException  {
        Workbook w;
        try {
          w = Workbook.getWorkbook((File)input);
          // Get the first sheet
          Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
          // Loop over first 10 column and lines
          for (int i = 5; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getColumns(); j++) {
              Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
              CellType type = cell.getType();
              if (type == CellType.LABEL) {
                System.out.print(cell.getContents() + ";");
              }
              if (type == CellType.NUMBER) {
                System.out.print(cell.getContents() + ";");
              }
            }
          System.out.println(i);
          }
        } catch (BiffException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

And the Exception from the Mule console is:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Started app 'imaptest'                                   +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2013-03-03 19:35:17,592 [[imaptest].imaptestflow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: [rtdata2.xls, rtdata.xlsx]
INFO  2013-03-03 19:35:17,598 [[imaptest].imaptestflow.stage1.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.1635258243'. Object is: FileMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-03-03 19:35:17,598 [[imaptest].imaptestflow.stage1.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.1635258243'. Object is: FileMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-03-03 19:35:17,601 [[imaptest].imaptestflow.stage1.02] org.mule.transport.file.FileConnector: Writing file to: C:\OUT\18a0c736-8431-11e2-b133-e9e7c6fca1c6rtdata2.xls
ERROR 2013-03-03 19:35:17,674 [[imaptest].imaptestflow.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{imaptestflow.commponent.569080239}. Message payload is of type: MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
    1. javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler cannot be cast to java.io.File (java.lang.ClassCastException)xlsFileRead:18 (null)
    2. Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{imaptestflow.commponent.569080239}. Message payload is of type: MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler (org.mule.component.ComponentException) org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter:352 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/component/ComponentException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler cannot be cast to java.io.File
at xlsFileRead.readFromFile(xlsFileRead.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Mule, but in general mail attachments should be accessed through streams (like BLOBs in database). You should get attachment from message and then get content from attachment.

Comment: Show the full exception, it's impossible to tell what's wrong from what you're sharing.

Comment: I've now added both the Java Class called from the flow and also the full exception. Any input is welcome! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Dear all, I would really appreciate if someone could bring som light to this. Is it possible to pass a attachment file to a java component with mule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now done a work around. I write the attachment to a file and then read it again.
It works and it's good enough for now.

Here's the code:

```
public class xlsFileRead {

public void readFromFile(Object input)throws IOException  {

    DataHandler handler = (DataHandler)input;
    String tempfilenm = handler.getName();
    InputStream is = handler.getInputStream();
    File tempfile =new File("c:\\tempdev\\" + tempfilenm);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tempfile);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    os.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
         }      
 Workbook w;
    try {
      w = Workbook.getWorkbook(tempfile);
      // Get the first sheet
      Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
      // Loop over first 10 column and lines
      for (int i = 5; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getColumns(); j++) {

          Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
          CellType type = cell.getType();
          if (type == CellType.LABEL) {
            System.out.print(cell.getContents() + ";");
          }

          if (type == CellType.NUMBER) {
            System.out.print(cell.getContents() + ";");
          }

        }
      System.out.println(i);
      }
    } catch (BiffException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}
}

Comment: What library/package is the source of the DataHandler class in the solution above?